# Coloring Different Arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm having troubles with adding a coloring code to my VBA code source. I have three different loops with arrays where it takes data from three different worksheets. I want to define a color for each loop so when I run the script there will be a color assigned to the data extracted from the specific worksheet. I originally thought it was an easy tasks, where I could just add `.Interior.ColorIndex = 67` to my array, but that definitely didn't work. Everytime I run the script it gives me an error where it says

> 'Object required'.

I have been trying to google to get an answer, but can't find a solution that works for my sheet. I hope somebody can help.

```
Option Explicit


'Function to return stakeholder name

Sub Simple_if()
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shE As Worksheet, shA As Worksheet, shC As Worksheet, lastRB As Long, lastRA As Long, lastRC As Long
 Dim score As Integer, i As Long, k As Long, arrB, arrA, arrC, arrE

'Worksheet definitions
 Set shB = Worksheets("Business")
 Set shA = Worksheets("Authorities")
 Set shC = Worksheets("Civil society")
 Set shE = Worksheets("Engagement Plan")
 
 
 lastRB = shB.Range("D" & shB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRA = shA.Range("D" & shA.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRC = shC.Range("D" & shC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 arrB = shB.Range("C6:D" & lastRB).Value 'put the shB sheet range in an array
 arrA = shA.Range("C6:D" & lastRA).Value
 arrC = shC.Range("C6:D" & lastRC).Value
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrB))      'redim arrE at maximum possible dimension
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrA))
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrC))

 
 
 'Loop for Business worksheet
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrB)
    If arrB(i, 2) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrB(i, 1) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
       arrE(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
       
    End If
       
 Next i
 
 'Loop for Authorities worksheet
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
    If arrA(i, 2) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrA(i, 1) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
        arrE(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 67
        
    End If
 Next i
 
 'Loop for Civil society worksheet
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrC)
    If arrC(i, 2) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrC(i, 1) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
        arrE(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        
    End If
 Next i
 
 ReDim Preserve arrE(k - 1)  'redim the array to keep only the filled elements

 'drop the array content at once:
 shE.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(arrE) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrE)

End Sub
```

Comment: your arr-variables hold *values* from a sheet, not cells. A value has no properties like `Interior`.

Comment: What gets populated is text from the different worksheet, does that make a difference? I need the background colored according to where the text was pulled form. When I do try to only use '.Color = RGB(50, 200, 100)', it gives me an error saying 'Subscript is out of range'.

Comment: You would need to store the colours in a separate array and loop through at the end.

Comment: You cannot color an array. You can only color a Range. After copying the data (values) from a Range to an Array, there is no link between them - you need to change you logic. I would suggest you create a Sub that is called three times and pass the Range and the expected color(-index) as parameter.